# Convert UTC timestamp to Simple binary encoded message

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, datetime-format

I am trying to convert UTC timestamp to simple binary encoded message.
Would like to achieve what is mentioned in example [here](https://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/MDP+3.0+-+Simple+Binary+Encoding).

```
Binary Encoding Example
The following timestamp:

 UTC timestamp 14:17:22 Friday, October 4, 2024

is expressed in binary code (nanoseconds since Unix epoch) this way:

 007420bf8838fb17 (8 bytes in nanoseconds since Unix epoch synced to a master clock to microsecond accuracy.
```

What I have done so far is,

```
import struct
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime(2024, 10, 4, 14, 17, 22, 0)
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds() * 1000000000
utc_timestamp = struct.pack('d', timestamp)
```

Output I see on CLI is `'\xf4\x02\x82\xa1E\xfb\xb7C'` but, as per example in shared link, expected is `007420bf8838fb17`

Comment: 'd' is for double-precision floating point: right size, but wrong format.  You need 'q' (or perhaps 'Q' if it's unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I think there's either an error in linked example, or the description of the representation is incorrect or incomplete.

```
import struct
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

utc_tz = timezone(timedelta(0))
t = datetime(2024, 10, 4, 14, 17, 22, 0, utc_tz)
nanos = int(t.timestamp()) * 1_000_000_000
print(hex(timestamp))
```

This gives the result of `0x17fb45a18202f400`, not the quoted `0x17fb3888bf297400` (as presented, I think it's a little-endian byte string, so this value has the order of bytes reversed).

The quoted answer, converted to decimal seconds (dividing by 1_000_000_000) is `1728037042.0005898`.  That value obviously has a sub-second quantity, which the source datetime does NOT have.

Decoding the seconds component of the quoted answer:

```
import time

answer = 0x17fb3888bf297400
secs = int(answer / 1_000_000_000)
print(time.gmtime(secs))
```

gives:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2024, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=4, tm_hour=10, tm_min=17, tm_sec=22, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=278, tm_isdst=0)
```

which looks *almost* correct, save that the hour component is 4 hours earlier.  So ... my *guess* is that this is actually a US/Eastern timestamp (not UTC), and contains a sub-second component of 5898ns, and the example is misleading.

*If* the schema you're using is encoding timestamps as a 64-bit number of nanoseconds since the Unix epoch (midnight 1 January 1970), then I think your example code has only one error: use format `<q` (or `<Q`) rather than `d`, and you'll get a little-endian 64-bit integer as required.  You will also need to convert the `timestamp` to an integer to have `struct.pack()` accept it.